# Dropdown list with sheet names. I need to set active sheet in a function based on selection in dropdown

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am stuck. I have a spreadsheet with a dropdown list containing the names of the sheets. Is it possible within a function to set the active spreadsheet to match the dropdown selection

```
function getNextCell() {
  // Active sheet should reflect dropdown selection
  // to find first empty cell of that sheet by dropdown
  var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var myValues = sheetTo.getRange('A:A').getValues();
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < myValues.length; i++) {
    if (myValues[i][0] === '')
      return i + 1;
  }
  return i + 1;
}
```

Sample sheet updated to show current work:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1befqsGQvbPfn0XTGrygLOGcrUIMrICUagJVH0S-2rDw/edit?usp=sharing

I should mention I tried an array but that didn't work for me. I may have been utilizing it wrong but am not sure.

Comment: Example sheet is now unlocked for edit access.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try using this onEdit(e)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Dropdown" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.value) {
    e.source.getSheetByName(e.value).activate();
  }
}
```

You can also create the list of all sheet names for the datavalidation in column H with this:

```
function makeColumnDropDown(col = 8) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const list = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list);
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Dropdown");
  sh.getRange(1,col,100).setDataValidation(r);
}
```

If you wish to leave some out you may also add a .filter method to the third line and  exclude a list of file names.  Just ask I show you.

#### The next empty row is columnHeight + 1

```
function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

Comment: When I tried it with another sample doc with full code it does not work...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1befqsGQvbPfn0XTGrygLOGcrUIMrICUagJVH0S-2rDw/edit?usp=sharing
Can you please try this there?

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine for me when I change any dropdown in column 8 it moves to the selected sheet based on name

Comment: Can you look at this sample sheet?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1befqsGQvbPfn0XTGrygLOGcrUIMrICUagJVH0S-2rDw/edit?usp=sharing
Possible to do a zoom call?

Comment: That's not the same as  your original sample sheet

Comment: Checked it just now adding your code and it does not work.
Correct MiMi. I added the rest of the code to try it out and it didn't work

Comment: The goal of this is to find first empty cell in column A of the sheet I'm copying the row to. The getNextCell function is where I'm stumped I need the sheetname to be dynamic based on column 9 of Sort page